# How to delete S3 folder based on filter criteria using policy?

Tags: amazon-s3

How to delete the objects in S3 bucket based on specified criteria using bucket policy?

> 1. Total object counts in the bucket should be more than 5 everytime.
> 2. Object should have a common prefix.
> 3. Object age should be more than X(1,2,3,4...n) days.

Bucket Structure -

```
myprefixtest1234bucket //bucket 
        |- prefixtestobject1 //object
        |- prefixtestobject2
        |- prefixtestobject3
        |- prefixtestobject4
        |- prefixtestobject5
        |- prefixtestobject6
        |- prefixtestobject7
        |- testobject8
        |- testobject9
```

> I am trying to delete the object in a bucket which has prefix
>   "prefixtext" and is older than X days and this bucket should keep Y
>   numbers of object all the time even if it is older than X days. Means keeping Y number of object should be given precedence over age (older than X days).

I tried below policy but didn't work and not sure how to add the age and object count logic.

```
{
"Id": "Policy123456",
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"TestBucketObjectDeletion",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": {"AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::123456789:root"]},
      "Action":["s3:DeleteObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::myprefixtest1234/*"],
      "Condition":{"StringEquals":{"myprefixtest1234"}}
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Currently, there is no way to specify to keep number(1,2,3....n) of
>   objects in the bucket and delete rest of them based on common prefix
>   but we can set the expiration of the bucket objects based on age using
>   bucket Life Cycle.

```
{
    "Rules": [
        {
            "Filter": {
                "Prefix": "documents/"
            },
            "Status": "Enabled",
            "Transitions": [
                {
                    "Days": 365,
                    "StorageClass": "GLACIER"
                }
            ],
            "Expiration": {
                "Days": 3650
            },
            "ID": "ExampleRule"
        }
    ]
}
```

And put it using s3api like this -

```
aws s3api put-bucket-lifecycle-configuration  \
--bucket bucketname  \
--lifecycle-configuration file://lifecycle.json
```

More info available here -
[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/set-lifecycle-cli.html) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/create-lifecycle.html).